# Iterating through classes with static functions

Tags: java, class, interface

I have Model class like this

```
class ModelName {
    public static void createTable(SQLiteDatabase db){
        // code to create Table in DB
    }

    public static void deleteTable(SQLiteDatabase db){
        // code to delete Table from DB
    }
}
```

Every class has these static functions `createTable`, `deleteTable`
I'd like to iterate through classes like this:

```
SQLiteDatabase db_object = ....; //init the object
Class<?>[] models = {ModelName, OtherModelName};
for(Class<?> model : models){
    model.deleteTable(db_object);
}
```

But defining Interface for `public static void` is not possible, and I have no reason to create Instances

How to achieve this?
Can't really find the right words to describe my idea

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/287654/106261

Comment: "I have no reason to create Instances" - This looks like a reason, if you want to avoid reflection.

Comment: I didn't want to avoid reflection, just forgot its existence :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for but I just tested it with following.

Classes:

```
class ModelName {
    public static void createTable(SQLiteDatabase db){
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]);
    }

    public static void deleteTable(SQLiteDatabase db){
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]);
    }
}

class OtherModelName {
    public static void createTable(SQLiteDatabase db){
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]);
    }

    public static void deleteTable(SQLiteDatabase db){
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]);
    }
}
```

Main code:

```
Class<?>[] models = {ModelName.class, OtherModelName.class};

for(Class<?> model : models){
    Method method = model.getMethod("createTable", SQLiteDatabase.class);
    method.invoke(null, new SQLiteDatabase());
    method = model.getMethod("deleteTable", SQLiteDatabase.class);
    method.invoke(null, new SQLiteDatabase());
}
```

Output:

```
demo.reflection.ModelName.createTable(IterateClassStaticMethod.java:12)
demo.reflection.ModelName.deleteTable(IterateClassStaticMethod.java:16)
demo.reflection.OtherModelName.createTable(IterateClassStaticMethod.java:22)
demo.reflection.OtherModelName.deleteTable(IterateClassStaticMethod.java:26)
```

Note: To me this looks like more overhead than just creating instances. Also, the code looks less readable and manageable like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (untested):

```
for(Class<?> model : models){
    model.getMethod("deleteTable",SQLiteDatabase.class).invoke(null,db_object);
}
```