# Determine whether Android method is static in an automated fashion

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I have a file of Android APIs in JNI format:

```
Landroid/accounts/AccountManager;->access$000(Landroid/accounts/AccountManager;)Landroid/accounts/IAccountManager;    
Ljava/lang/Runtime;->exec([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/File;)Ljava/lang/Process;
Ldalvik/system/DexClassLoader;->findLibrary(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
...
```

However, none of them contain access modifiers. I would like to determine whether each of them is static in an automated fashion.

Comment: Do you want to do it just on the basis of those prototype strings or can you access the API?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, yes I can use the SDK. As far as I can tell, it contains a source folder that contains most of the class definitions in which the methods are implemented. However, for example I couldn't find above mentioned DexClassLoader there. Do you know where the system classes are defined?

Comment: Presuming I have all the source files, then I guess I have to write a script that searches them for the desired signatures and checks whether they are prefixed by static. As I am inexperienced in scripting, I would appreciate if you pointed me in the right direction as to which commands you would use.

Comment: I guess I have to extract method name and parameter types from the signatures above and then create a regexp that I can use to grep the appropriate line of a source file. Then that line will begin with a visibility modifier (i.e. public) and is possibly followed by other modifiers like final or static. Would checking whether the second word is "static" then be sufficient? Finally, how do I perform this check using a linux command and modify the original file accordingly.

Many thanks for your time!

Comment: Try using reflection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287645/how-can-i-check-if-a-method-is-static-using-reflection

Comment: Thanks! I implemented your suggestion and it worked beautifully. Also gave me the chance to explore reflection, which I had previously only heard of. Would you like to post your comment as an answer so I can mark it accepted?

Comment: Great, glad that worked for you. I've posted my comment as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether a method is static using Java [Reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)#Java).

For example, you can obtain a Class object from an object using getClass(), and call getDeclaredMethod() on the class object to get a Method object using the method name and the classes of the method parameters:

```
Class[] methodParameters = new Class[]{Integer.TYPE, String.class};
Method method = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("methodName", methodParameters);
```

Then you can query the Method object to check if it is static:

```
boolean isStatic = Modifier.isStatic(method.getModifiers());
```

You can get a class object based on the class name like this:

```
Class c = Class.forName("com.example.TestClass");
```